# Unlimited Security (Jasypt/WebSphere)

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, jce, jasypt

I am trying to encrypt a few password in a properties file using an Ant script. When I run the Ant script I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Security Error in doEncrypt: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256 SecretKeyFactory not available
```

this is with `org.jasypt.util.text.AES256TextEncryptor`. So I tried to move to `PooledPBEStringEncryptor` and that throws `org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException`

I have this in the code for the latter:

```
Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");

pooledPBEStringEncryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();

pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setPassword(encryptionKey);
pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHHMACSHA512AND256BITAES");
pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setPoolSize(4);
pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setSaltGenerator(new RandomSaltGenerator());
```

This is how I initialize the object.

I am on WebSphere 8.5.5.10 and JAVA8 on a Unix system. My JDK version is:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr3ifix-20160713_01(SR3+IX90174+IV85763))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20160713_311397 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20160713_0915_B311397
JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20160329_114288
GC   - R28_Java8_SR3_20160713_0915_B311397_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160713_311397)
JCL - 20160421_01 based on Oracle jdk8u91-b14
```

Any advise would be nice. I searched for IBM WebSpehre forums, but couldn't find any. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

1. How to verify the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files used
   on local_policy.jar & US_export_policy.jar and also How to check the
   list of ciphers used by IBM Java?

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1171564

Comment: Even with those two jars, the problem remains with `PooledPBEStringEncryptor`

Comment: Did you download  JDKCiphersList.java and verify that the unlimited strength Jurisdiction files were in fact being used?